# Cost for Clound Foundry on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-foundry, cost-management

I have seen instructions for installing Bosh Lite on AWS. It's a similar process to installing it on a local VM. Then I can utilize Bosh to deploy OSS Cloud Foundry to the bosh-lite VM. Here are those instructions:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/blob/master/docs/aws-provider.md

My question is how can I estimate how much this would cost?  I want to charge this on my company credit card, but I need to estimate the cost first.  I know I can get a plain EC2 instance free for a year (I assume there's some limit to how much I use it), but from the looks of the instructions above, I think I'll need several, along with other instances.

So, if I just set up Cloud Foundry, write a simple "Hello World" web app using Spring, deploy my app and test it, and then tear everything down, how can I estimate the cost?

Comment: Not sure if applicable but does this tool help? https://pcfsizer.cfapps.io/#!/sizing/aws/1.11/large

Answer (score 0):

AWS costs vary with the services, regions, data in/out etc.

So list down the aws region you want to use, list all the number of resources & their types (Ex. EC2 - t2.medium) and approximate storage etc everything.

Then go to AWS calculator and feed all those entries and it will show you the costs.

Here is calculator link: https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html